# .htaccess redirect except one subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need following type redirection:
/store/something/namestore to /store/namestore
However there is one exception:
/store/namestore/page/2 should not redirect to anything.
/store/namestore/page/3 should not redirect to anything. and so on.

Comment: If you need something try to do something.

Answer (score 0):

If i understud the question right, this should be the solution.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/store/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)$  /store/$2/   [R]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/store/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  /store/$2/   [R]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. anyway I still have problem because links like "/store/namestore/page/2" and "/store/namestore/page/3" are still being redirected. If the link contains page the redirection should be voided. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: I need some  kind of RewriteCond to not allow redirection for the above problem

Comment: I changed the answer, try this

Comment: by the way your redirection don't work for some reason at me.

Comment: it doesn't redirect anything. I can give the full .htaccess file if that helps

Comment: I have a working redirection but the page exception doesn't work: RedirectMatch 301 /stores/(.*)/(?!page)(.*)/ http://www.mywebsite.com/stores/$2

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in case someone else need:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stores/(.+)/page/.*$ 
RewriteRule stores/(.+)/(.+) stores/$2 [R=301,L]